# How can I access specific columns from a CSV file and add it to a list without using external modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, list, for-loop

```
def loadCSVData(filename):          
    list = []
    fileContent = open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf8')
    for line in fileContent:
        # HERE
    fileContent.close()
    return list
```

If I were to have a csv file that has 3 columns:

```
 name job pay
1   
2
3
4
```

how can I access the name column and add the contents to the list?
I want to be able to acess this without the need of pandas or numpy or anything else.

Comment: You need to have prior knowledge of the file's format. What defines a header? How would a header be different than the rest of the data? Open the file in a text editor and look at the first line - does it look like names of the columns?

Comment: `# if this line is a header (first line) you need to skip` - are they giving you a hint that the **first** line **is** a header?  Search SO for something like `'python skip the first line of a file in a for loop'`.

Comment: yeah it's a header in both files, I thought there is a specific way to detect a header, its like bolded and the first column.

Comment: A [csf file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is plain text.

Comment: yea ur right I just noticed, I changed my question, thanks for your first answer, do you know how to answer this one?

Comment: Please don't morph your questions. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: sorry usually they dont allow me to post more than once every four days.

Comment: If your problem has been solved without an Answer you could choose to delete it unless you think it has value to the community or [you can answer your own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - be sure to read through [Anwersing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).

Comment: Bold isn't a thing for plain text files like CSV. What is the file type (the file extension would be a good hint)?

Comment: it is a CSV i just realised that it wasnt bolded, im passed that problem

Comment: If this is a csv, you have to know which character is used to separate entries (a comma - the c in csv - tabs, vertical bars, semicolons are a common). Then how to quote an entry to escape separators that happen to be part of the data (usually `"`). Then the escape character (usually \). Then if you don't want to use other modules, you'd have to parse character by character, taking account of those tokens.

Comment: Is the `csv` module in the standard library considered "external"?

Comment: no it is not considierd

Answer (score 0):

You can split the columns in each row yourself - at your own risk. Assuming this is a traditional CSV file, you could

```
def loadCSVData(filename):
    with open(filename) as fileobj:
        header = next(fileobj).strip().split(",")
        if header != ["name", "job", "pay"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid CSV file")
        return [line.strip().split(",")[0] for line in fileobj]
```

This will work fine if the values of the CSV don't have commas in them. But suppose `name` was `"Doe, John"`, (an interior comma, surrounding quotes), then you'd have a problem because you would split on that comma. If that's the case, you could write a more complex parser... or just use the existing `csv` module in standard lib.